# Changing cipher list of a ctx object after connection establishment

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection, ciphers

Does changing the cipher list for a CTX object (using SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list), have any effect on the already established connections (connections that had used that very CTX object)?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the SSL context does not affect the current SSL session which was created using the context object. The cipher for the session gets set during the TLS handshake and is valid until the end of the TLS session.